# Best way to control the amount of charges generated by a Van de Graaf machine?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

Lately I have been looking at some electrostatic generators and their design. The Van de Graaf seems to be the most common. Because it is used also in particle accelerators, do people actually control how much charge the machine generates? If so, how? I know I can just reduce the motor speed and the machine will pump charges much slower, but is it possible with some ways to control how much charge it generates at any given point in time?

Comment: Having lots of experience running VdG accelerators, what exactly do you mean by controlling how much charge? Usually we try to control the voltage on the terminal, which does require balancing the up-charge (which you change with a slow response rate) with net ion current, column current, and corona current (which is the fast response).

Comment: https://www.pelletron.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/TPS-v1.pdf is a quick overview of real accelerator control.

Comment: gregory112, do you want to control the maximum charge on the sphere, or do you want to control the rate at which the sphere charges?

Comment: @DavidWhite the maximum charge on the sphere, or better, the charge the sphere holds at an arbitrary point in time. I guess changing the rate at which the sphere charges is quite straightforward right? Just reduce the motor and thus the belt speed?

Comment: @JonCuster Well, the amount of charge the sphere is having. Can you elaborate "controlling the voltage on the terminal"? Does that mean you control the voltage of the motor driving the generator?

Answer (score 0):

since you know the capacity of the top sphere , you can measure the voltage and calculate the charge.

Comment: No real accelerator operates this way.

Comment: I guess having to calculate the charge requires a lot of other parameters like the shape of the dome and it may produce inaccurate results, other than measuring the charge directly?

Answer (score 0):

I will discuss actual practice on real accelerators used in physics. Not those nice (but still 'toy') devices you can pick up on Amazon for a few hundred dollars.

Not this:
[image: VdG you can buy]

This:

[image: HVE EN Tandem low energy end]

So, lets talk about how real Van de Graaff ion accelerators operate, with a purpose of creating an ion beam at a constant voltage. First, a very brief description can be found at [National Electrostatics Corporation](http://pelletron.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/TPS-v1.pdf) website. (NEC manufactures a variant of the Van de Graaff, based on the Pelletron chain instead of a rubber belt. Robert J. Van de Graaff's company, High Voltage Engineering, went out of business some decades ago. High Voltage Engineering Europa, which was part of the HVE conglomerate, did not go down with the mothership and still exists today.)

To hold the terminal of a VdG accelerator at a constant potential, you need to put a certain net charge on it, and then balance the current flows. The possible currents are:

1. Charge on the belt going up and coming down from the terminal (high current machines will use both - positive charge up and negative charge down for a positively charged terminal, opposite if you want an electron beam machine).
2. Column current. Down the column of the machine there are a series of high resistivity resistors that act to bleed current from the terminal back to ground. While, in theory, one could use the measured column current to back-calculate what the terminal potential is, it is really hard to get precise measurements of the resistance of the giga-ohm resistor chain. One illustration of these resistors (from [High Voltage Engineering Europa](http://www.highvolteng.com/Ion_Accelerator_Systems_en.html)) looks like the picture below. The red bars on the top of the column are the high value resistors responsible for evenly grading the potential drop down the column structure. The column structure holds up the terminal, carries the vacuum beam line, belt/chain, and control links, and keeps the voltage gradient roughly constant down the length.

[image: HVEE column]

3. Ion/electron current. The total charge in your beams (down from a source in the terminal if a single-ended machine, total up and down charge for a tandem accelerator).
4. Corona current, extracted from the terminal through sharp conductors (needle-like) placed at an appropriate distance from the terminal. The corona probe is moved in and out depending on the desired terminal voltage to keep the range of corona current in a consistent range. Corona current [control](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1769991) was perfected in 1942, with essentially the same circuit still used today.

The voltage on the terminal is measured with a [generating voltmeter](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1751641), also invented pretty early on and still in essentially the same form today. (John Trump, lead author on that paper, a professor at MIT, was one of the founders of High Voltage Engineering with Van de Graaff. He was also the uncle of the current president, an odd coincidence.)

So, what and how are things controlled to keep the voltage constant?

Well, you can control the current(s) induced onto the belt/chain through the inductive power supplies at the base of the machine and possibly up at the terminal as well. These change the voltage used to put charge on the belt or chain. The belt/chain speed is kept constant, mostly because it is also used to drive a generator in the terminal to power the electronics there.  The belt speed is roughly 2 revolutions per second, so it takes on the order of a half second before changes to the belt charge make it to the terminal.

As the terminal potential changes, the current going down the column will change in concert, since I = V/R (although the resistors do often have a sight voltage sensitivity). But, generally this is a fully passive system and you don't control the column current.

The ion/electron current comes from a ion/electron source, which you generally want to try to have output a pretty constant current. Those who have lots of experience have seen, more than they would like, sources 'blink', but a well behaved source can be quite stable.

Finally, you have corona current which, while limited in total current (you don't want a lightning strike!), has a very fast response time, much faster than the belt charge. Thus the corona current is the rapid adjustment of terminal voltage, while belt charge is the slow adjustment.

You can also adjust terminal voltage based on the observed beam current after a turning magnet where you have selected a particular ion species with the magnet. You then pass the beam through two vertical slits, each with a current monitor. Any deviation of terminal voltage will drive the ion beam towards one side or the other as the ions get bent different amounts by the magnetic field. Keeping the current on the two slits constant means keeping the ion energy constant. However, the slit control module just uses the belt and corona currents in the same way as above to maintain as constant an energy as possible on the terminal.

There are a number of overviews of accelerators on the web, [this one from UW](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwig2vSQppjrAhVeAp0JHdvrA3oQFjAFegQIBhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.fnal.gov%2F%7Ekubik%2FAccelerators%2FUW_vanDeGraaff.pdf&usg=AOvVaw07VLJ0SdHMFUtWtdZ-lIII) looks pretty good.

Comment: A column in this context I assume is the center "pillar" of the machine, that holds the dome? How do you make such column with highly resistive resistors?

Comment: Can you provide me a design/illustration about how to control charges carried by the belt using inductive power supply? Also I have been thinking about a design which you say is the corona current control. I am looking for ways to control charges in a smaller generator, not for ion accelerator. I guess it's still possible to control it by adding sharp electrode near the terminal?

Comment: We seem to be talking about different things. You seem to be thinking of a 'toy' Van de Graaff, say from Amazon, while I'm talking about the real deal.

Comment: The principles do not apply to small generators?

Comment: The small generators you might buy on Amazon don't have column resistors, corona points, or control of charge put on the belt. They are not made for precise voltage control, but to make exciting sparks. Sure, we have one in the lobby of the ion beam lab, but it is not meant to be a controllable device.

Comment: I actually don't have intention of "buying" one, I am trying to design one. So I can add any components. That is why I'm interested with your explanation too.